# I am confused with various use of combinatorics, can anyone help me to clarify my concepts?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am quite confused with the ways to calculate different combinations of indistinguishable and distinguishable objects and containers. Thanks

> $(a)$ How many ways to distribute $10$ books to $4$ boys (note that the books are different)?

My answer: $\color{red}{4^{10}}$

> $(b)$ How many ways to distribute $10$ books to $4$ boys so that the oldest boy gets $4$ books and the other two boys get $2$ books each?

My answer: $\color{red}{\frac {10!}{4! \times 2! \times 2! \times2!}}$

> $(c)$ How many ways to distribute $10$ candies to $4$ boys (note that the candies are indistinguishable)?

My answer: $\color{red}{13\choose3}$

> $(d)$ How many ways to distribute $10$ candies to $4$ boys so that the oldest boy gets at least $2$ candies and every boy gets at least one candy?

My answer:  $\color{red}{8\choose 3}$

Comment: You seem to be doing quite well in your confusion !

Answer (score 0):

> $(a)$ How many ways to distribute $10$ books to $4$ boys (note that the
>    books are different)? my answer: $4^{10}$

Yup. Consider an application from the set of the books to the set of the boys. It is built by choosing an image to all the 10 books.

> $(b)$ How many ways to distribute $10$ books to $4$ boys so that the oldest
>    Boy gets $4$ books and the other two boys get $2$ books each? My answer:
>    $\frac {10!}{4! \times 2! \times 2! \times 2!}$

You mean "the three other boys", I guess.
A way to do this : choose $4$ books for the elder $10\choose 4$, $2$ for the second kid $6\choose 2$, $2$ for the third $4\choose 2$ and give the last to to the last boy $2\choose 2$.

So there are ${10\choose 4}\times {6\choose 2}\times {4\choose 2}\times {2\choose 2}$ ways to do this (IF, of course, the $4$ boys are distinguishable).

> $(c)$ How many ways to distribute $10$ candies to $4$ boys (note that the
>    candies are indistinguishable)? my answer: $13\choose 3$

Are the boys distinguishable ?

> $(d)$ How many ways to distribute $10$ candies to $4$ boys so that the
>    oldest boy gets at least $2$ candies and every boy gets at least one
>    candy? my answer: $8\choose 3$

This one requires some adding, or some substracting ;-)

Comment: for c the boys are distinguishable

for d do u mean i have to use inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: @soulless Yes, and so you did. All your answers are okay.

Comment: Can you explain to me how to use the principle in detail? because I am only using the formula taught but i want to understand the rationale behind

Answer (score 0):

Your answers are all ok. The explanations you seek are given below:

(a) Each book has 4 places to go to, so $4^{10}$

(b) Permute the 10 books in a line, place dividers for the boys, and remove permutations *within* each boy's books.

(c) [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) formula for $\Sigma x_i = N, x_i \ge 0$

(d) No [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), *preplace* $2+1+1+1$ candies to take care of constraints, and then proceed as for (c).